# Denormalize table and append data

Tags: sqlite, denormalization

I want to denormalize the following table

```
+----+-------+
| ID | LINK  |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    43 |
|  1 |    55 |
|  1 |    98 |
|  2 |    66 |
|  2 |    23 |
+----+-------+
```

as

```
+-------+----------+
|  ID   |  LINK    |
+-------+----------+
| 1,1,1 | 43,55,98 |
| 2,2   | 66,23    |
+-------+----------+
```

How do I do it? What should be the query?

Comment: No. I mean the same that I have posted as question. Is it possible?

Comment: [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat)

Comment: Why on Earth would anyone ever want to DEnormalize a table? Normalization is to be **always** pursued. If you are sane, of course. Which I curiously tend to take for granted, it seems.